# how to post a link with requests in Python

Tags: python, python-requests

Right now I'm working on my first python project. It is suppose to take a random video from a YouTube search and then add it to Watch2Gether. Right now my code looks like this:

```
# Take a random video from my youtube recommended and add it to watch2gether
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import time
import random
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
# Importing libraries

def GetVideos(): # Function to generate videos from youtube

    num = random.randint(1, 20)
    recommended = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=svenska+youtube+klassiker&sp=EgIQAQ%253D%253D')
    recommended_soup = BS(recommended.content, features='lxml')
    all_links = recommended_soup.find_all('a', href=True)
    my_links = [] #Just a empty list to story all /watch links

    for link in all_links:
        if '/watch' in link['href']:
            print(link['href'])
            my_links.append(link['href'])
#check for all the /watch and appends them to my emty list

    print('www.youtube.com' + my_links[num])

ua = UserAgent()
print(ua.random)
URL = "https://www.watch2gether.com/rooms/zgabjnblvqy52vam0c"
r = requests.get(URL, data={'class': 'w2g-messages-input'})
# And done.
print(r.text) # displays the result body.
```

My goal is to make my program join my "room" and then add random videos. I have figured out how to get all the links to the videos, but I can't get it to post them to the "room". Appreciate all help! :) Just leave a comment if you need more information.

Comment: `requests.get`? You seem to be using POST.

Comment: Oh thanks but I still can figure out how to post the links to the room, but now I get the html from the site.

Comment: You will have to see if watch2gether has some sort of API for that. You can't simply change the HTML of a page response and expect it to change for everyone else. https://www.watch2gether.com/pages/tools?lang=en

Comment: No like watch2gether is a website where you can add videos from youtube and watch them with your friends. So I want to take a video from youtube and add it to my watch2gether "room".

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments the first things you should do is change `requests.get` to `requests.post`.

What I would also recommend you doing is changing `data={'class': 'w2g-messages-input'}` to `json={'class': 'w2g-messages-input'}`.

so your line of code that is sending the request will look like this:

```
r = requests.post(URL, json={'class': 'w2g-messages-input'})
```

hope this helps.